# Converting excel formulas to their number value VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Worksheets("Risk Plan").Range("U2:U800").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(IF(RC[-1]<=0,"" "",(RC[-1]/RC[-2])*100),"" "")"
Worksheets("Risk Plan").Range("V2:V800").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]<>"" "",(IF(RC[-1] * 0.75 >= RC[-16],""1"",(IF(AND(RC[-1] * 0.75 < RC[-16] = TRUE, RC[-16] < RC[-1] = TRUE),""2"",(IF(RC[-16] >= RC[-1], ""3"", "" "")))))),"" "")"
```

Above is an example of some code I'm using to populate cells in a sheet with excel formulas.

**My problem** is that I do not know how to convert the output of these formulas into an integer value which I can use in calculation in the rest of my code. I am referencing the cells which contain the values used in calculation with `xlCell.Offset(x, y).Value`. I read somewhere that multiplying the range where I want my formulas to show their number values by 1 will give number values, but this method has caused more problems than solutions. Grateful for any help or suggestions.

Comment: Why in the second formulla you use string `""3""` instead of `3`? If you want to have it as integer you can achieve it already in the formula. You need also to convert `"" ""` into `0`. You can also use `VALUE` function in formulas but it may cause error in converting `"" ""`.

Comment: I didn't realise I could omit the ""___"" notation! Thank you! What are you referring to when you say  "convert "" "" into 0"?

Comment: For example: `Worksheets("Risk Plan").Range("V2:V800").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]<>0,(IF(RC[-1] * 0.75 >= RC[-16],1,(IF(AND(RC[-1] * 0.75 < RC[-16] = TRUE, RC[-16] < RC[-1] = TRUE),2,(IF(RC[-16] >= RC[-1], 0, 0)))))),0)"` - of course if you need to have 'space', not '0', you will need to add additional check for convirting it into integer

Comment: Oh I understand, thank you I'll try this now.

Comment: If you wish to replace the formulas with their result: `Worksheets("Risk Plan").Range("U2:V800").Value2 = Worksheets("Risk Plan").Range("U2:V800").Value2` will do the trick